# How to automatically append slash to article links?

Tags: articles

I want to make sure that all my links from one article to another end in a '/'.

Currently, there is a link on article "One" that contains a link to "Two" and it's generated like this:

```
https://example.com/two
```

I want it to be generated like this:

```
https://example.com/two/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a custom plugin that will just do a find and replace on all the links in the body of the HTML and append a forward slash.

Alternatively, you can add a rule to your .htaccess file to have the links 301 redirected. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7781331/916491).

Comment: Would you mind putting a bit more of the "beef" in this answer?